# Windows Gem Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, rubygems, gravatar

I'm a newbie to Ruby on Rails. I had a quick question about installing gems.

I'm using a windows 7 64 bit machine with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0 and I'm trying to install the **gravatar_image_tag gem**.

`gem install gravatar_image_tag`

After I run that it says its succcessful. But when I try to do this:

`gravatar_image_tag -v`

It says that  `'gravatar_image_tag' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'`

When i looked into my ruby192/bin file there are batch files for rails, annotate etc etc that work fine but there's not batch file for gravatar_image_tag.

I was wondering where I'm going wrong with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer was right can you please mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Not all gems are executable from the command line.  The best way to see if a gem is installed (as well as its version) is to run:

```
gem list
```

Comment: `gem list --local` will keep it from hanging while trying to query the repository

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a gem inside your rails 3 project, you should add it to your `Gemfile` (in the root of your project). Something like this

```
gem "gravatar_image_tag"
```

then run `bundle install`.

The `gravatar_image_tag` should placed somewhere in your view, to generate the correct html.

More information can be found on t[heir github page](http://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag).

[EDIT] Maybe my answer was not too the point. To check if the gem was correctly installed, you either type

```
gem list gravatar_image_tag
```

or

```
bundle show gravatar_image_tag
```

if you installed the gem using bundler.

Not all gems install a batch-file, and according to the documentation this doesn't either.